# How to fix libcmcurl.dll not being found when trying to use cmake?

Tags: windows, cmake

Haven't found anything online as most threads are focused of libcurl rather than libcmcurl.

For some reason my Cmake stopped working in Windows 10. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling, however even basic commands like `cmake --version` return the following error message:

```
cmake.exe - System Error

The code execution cannot procees because libcmcurl.dll was not found. 
Reinstalling the program may fix the problem.
```

I tried running `cmake --version` when cmake was uninstalled and got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the source of the error was since even google refuses to show results for this file (defaults to `libcurl.dll`), however I think I solved the issue by repairing the Visual Studio 2019 install.

- Open Visual Studio Installer
- Click `More`
- `Repair`

Worked after that.